# Google Cloud Storrage Bucket Domain Permision

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to add a domain to my bucket permisions, but when I use the UI I get the following error:

> One of your permissions is invalid Make sure that you enter an
>   authorized id or email for the groups and users and a domain for the
>   domains

When I try to use the gsutil command line tool, I get the following error:

```
$ gsutil acl ch -g mydomain.com:R gs://my-bucket-name

CommandException: Received bad request from server: BadRequestException: 400 Could not find domain "mydomain.com".
```

Mydomain.com is ofcourcse used here as an example.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but are you sure that you have a Google Apps domain named "mydomain.com"? It's specific to Google Apps domain, not any domain name.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough Like e mentioned in the question; Mydomain.com is an example.

Comment: No, what I mean is, do you have a Google Apps domain that matches the real value?

Comment: yeah, and I figured it out. After adding my domain to Google Webmaster Tools it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifying my domain with Google Webmaster Tools and adding the Service Account Email Address as a verified owner of the domain, it worked.

Comment: where did you add the service account email address to and where did you get it?

Comment: Check out https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances and https://www.google.com/webmasters/ and https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication

Comment: Sorry its not working, can you please guide me

Comment: Could you please explain these steps "Service Account Email Address as a verified owner of the domain"